# How does Call hierarchy graph work in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, call-graph

I'm trying to implement a call hierarchy graph view like the way that eclipse has. Is there any source code or any information that explains how it works?

Comment: This is the [JDT plugin home](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php#DEV) I good place to start I believe.

Comment: Eclipse is open source, all the source code is available (but is very complex). For a general overview of the Eclipse JDT abstract syntax tree used to do this sort of thing see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html). Eclipse JDT source is on Github [here](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt)